# How do I check if an issue is a pull request?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm building a Github App. I receive an [`issue_comment`](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuecommentevent) webhook. Is there any quick way for me to know whether the comment was made in a pull request of not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Issues API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue)...

> Note: GitHub's REST API v3 considers every pull request an issue, but not every issue is a pull request. For this reason, "Issues" endpoints may return both issues and pull requests in the response. You can identify pull requests by the pull_request key.

You should be able to look at `comment["issue"]["pull_request"]`.